# How to create error free CSS/XHTML joomla

Tags: joomla

What is error free CSS/XHTML in joomla templates? I see that all the time, but I am not sure if that means the `404` page or not and how can I create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this content this would be referring to 'valid' CSS and HTML.

You can validate CSS here: 
https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

And HTML here: 
https://validator.w3.org/

For the second part of the question creating an error document, you can add 'error.php' to the root of your template folder. This template file will be loaded instead of index.php if there is a 404, etc error. Have a look at default 'protostar' for an example of the implementation. For more information refer to: https://docs.joomla.org/Custom_error_pages